# How to Add Google Account Without Syncing Contacts on android

Tags: contacts, sync, google-contacts

I was looking to add a second account to my Android phone running Android version 12. The issue that I keep running into is that as soon as I sign in the contacts from that account are synced and my call records get all messed up.

There are some tutorials on the web that suggest that I turn the wifi (Internet) off as soon as I sign-in and then go to settings and disable contact sync.

I did try it but it does not work as the contacts are synced before I can turn off the interent.

I am looking for a permanent way and not a work around.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding the account, simply disable or take away contact permissions from the apps which are getting *messed up*. You can then go on to disable contact sync settings and enable or give the apps their permissions back.

Comment: This seems doable. But its crazy imo that there is no straightforward way of doing this. Just ask me do I wana sync contacts of not when I add the account.